# Create a json_encode string from PHP array

Tags: php, jquery

I am sending an array from arduino to PHP using php_serial.class. This part is working fine. My PHP array will be in the following format

`$myArray{"EQ:24","YR15", "MTH: 2", "100 MPH",0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}.`

There are 12 values in the array. I am very new to working with php, jquery, and quite frankly programming. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how I can send this array from PHP to an html page. I am guessing json_encode would work good for this. The text strings I want to update text boxes in jquery with and the 0's and 1's I want to update sliders states with.

Comment: You seem to already know what is required as you state in your question so you should have a go at the code.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: PHP to html ?? how can handle this array in html without php ?

Comment: you can send data php to html but i didn't handle data in html without php

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't very clear. And I may not be asking the question correctly because of my lack of understanding. My question is if I call for the json string from javascript on the html page to the php page. and my php sends an array like the one listed in original question. What will be the format of the json_encode string. Let's say $myArray[5] contains the status of slider1 how will I read the $myArray[5] to refresh slider1 once the json_encode string is received in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> POST data is data that is handled server side. And Javascript is on client side. So there is no way you can read a post data using JavaScript in html page.

you can call ajax request to php page and php page print a json or in any 
    format data,so you can handle that data from your html page.you need to just print data in php file.

**PHP**

```
$json_format = json_encode($array);
echo $json_format;
```

Comment: I ran your example in the php page and this was the result of the echo:    [ "EQ:24","YR15", "MTH: 2", "100 MPH",0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]:     Now how do I access each comma separated value in JS to update HTML elements associated with each one?

Comment: you need to call ajax requesst to this php file